# Не могу найти сертификат из X509Store

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wcf

За что отвечает последний параметр validOnly в методе X509Certificate2Collection.Find

```
X509Store store = new X509Store("MY", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection collection = store.Certificates;
X509Certificate2Collection signerCerts = collection.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "73C34288B66608BFD1AD69CC3A6A76C2E848F4D9", false);
X509Certificate2Collection countersignerCerts = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(
                signerCerts, 
                "Test Certificate Select", 
                "Select a certificate from the following list to get information on that certificate", X509SelectionFlag.MultiSelection);
```

Ибо в случае если он false, то он возвращает нужный мне сертификат, если же true, то какие бы параметры я в него не передалавал - он ничего не возвращает

Comment: значит сертификат не истек, и ему есть доверие. т.е. самоподписные он не отобразит,  если их нет в корневых.

Comment: открой оснастку CertMgr.msc, посмотри на свой сертификат(личное), есть ли ему доверие со стороны ос. есть ли закрытый ключ, и не истек ли его период действия.